# Indeterminacy of 1^(infinity)

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I am being taught that 1^(infinity) is indeterminate. But I couldn't stop thinking why 1x1x1x1....=1 is incorrect.

Please tell me if my reasoning is correct?

I thought like this. So, for limit to exist, LHL must be equal to RHL. left hand limit and right hand limit came different for 1^(infinity). For LHL, I took a value slightly lower than 1, which is now a fraction. And (Fraction)^(infinity) is 0 (zero). For RHL, I took number slightly greater than 1, which is NOT a fraction, and hence its power raised to infinity is infinity. So LHL and RHL are not equal.

Hence, indeterminacy arises only at 1 and not at numbers like 2, 3 etc. Because, then LHL and RHL will both be equal.

Is my Reasoning Correct? Is there a theoretical way to prove it?

Comment: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 1^x=1.$$

Comment: $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \ldots = 1$ is true (in the sense that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1^n = 1$.) That's not what is meant by "$1^\infty$ is indeterminate form". What that means is that you cannot draw any conclusions about $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n^{b_n}$ by knowing only $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 1$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = \infty$. For example, $1 + 1/n \rightarrow 1$ and $n^2 \rightarrow \infty$ but $(1+1/n)^{n^2} \rightarrow \infty$.